# Contador javascript para llamar funcion ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

estoy empezando con JavaScript y Ajax y necesito un ayudita pls. Tengo dos funciones Ajax que cargan HTML a un div asignado, dentro hay un contador de segundos que refresca la función Ajax(funciona!) pero cuando le doy al botón para pasar a la otra función Ajax se me queda el contador anterior en marcha y me refresca la función de antes y la nueva (vaya lioo!) os dejo el código por aquí

```
<script>
function loadactivity () {  
    \$.post("http://miweb/ajax.cgi",
        {
        'action': "activity",
        'region': "$region",
        'bracket': "$bracket"
        },
        function(data){
            \$("#activity").html(data);
        }
    );
}
function loadtracking () {  
    \$.post("http://miweb/ajax.cgi",
        {
        'action': "tracking",
        'region': "$region",
        'bracket': "$bracket"
        },
        function(data){
            \$("#activity").html(data);
        }
    );
}
function countdown(action, seconds) {
    if (action == "stop") {
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    else {
        var count = seconds;
        var timerId = setInterval(function() {
            count--;
            document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = count;
            if(count == 0) {
                clearInterval(timerId);
                if (action == "activity") {
                    loadactivity();
                }
                if (action == "tracking") {
                    loadtracking();
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
loadactivity();
 </script>
```

En las funciones Ajax va lo siguiente:

```
<script>
countdown("stop");
countdown("activity", 30);
</script>
```

Comment: las variables $región $bracket y las \ detrás del $ es porque estoy imprimiendo desde Perl

Comment: El problema está claro, tienes dos contadores refrescando el mismo elemento, pero ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: Pues que el contador de loadactivity y loadtracking se pare cuando cambie a una de las funciones, osea la que no este cargada

Comment: A ver si me aclaro: ¿Es [esto](http://jsbin.com/yenohonaqi/2/edit?html,js,output) tu escenario? ¿Quieres que si pulsas en los dos botones, no sobreescriban el contador ambos "intervalos", cancelándose el más antiguo? ¿Y que si pulso stop se pare?

Comment: si, exacto. son dos pestañas y cuando paso de una a otra el contador de la anterior no para y a los x segundos me carga la pestaña de antes

Comment: No es ese exactamente el escenario, porque lo que yo quiero es un interval de x segundos que se repita hasta que el usuario cambie de pestaña, entonces detenga el interval de la antigua pestaña y haga uno de la nueva pestaña

Answer (score 1):

Ya logre que funcione. El problema estaba en la variable timerId, no podía acceder a ella en el if stop pq aun no estaba declarada, alfinal me quedo este código:

```
...
var timerId;
function countdown(action, seconds) {
    var count = seconds;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        count--;
        document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = count;
        if(count == 0) {
            stopinterval();
            if (action == "activity") {
                loadactivity();
            }
            if (action == "tracking") {
                loadtracking();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
function stopinterval () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

y en la funciónes que llama Ajax

```
<script>
stopinterval();
countdown("tracking", 60);
</script>
```

Comment: Deberías seleccionar la respuesta como aceptada, para que así la pregunta quede marcada como *respondida*